# Typeorm doesn't work with Serverless Framework AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, typeorm, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

Well, basically I get this error when I try to `serverless deploy` or `serverless offline`:

```sh
PS C:\Users\joaov\Desktop\lambda-ts> serverless offline
Running "serverless" from node_modules
X [ERROR] Could not resolve "mock-aws-s3"

    node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/s3_setup.js:43:28:
      43 │     const AWSMock = require('mock-aws-s3');
         ╵                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "mock-aws-s3" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove 
  this error. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this      
  failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "nock"

    node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/s3_setup.js:112:23:
      112 │   const nock = require('nock');
          ╵                        ~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "nock" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this   
  error. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at
  run-time instead of bundle-time.

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "pg-native"

    node_modules/pg/lib/native/client.js:4:21:
      4 │ var Native = require('pg-native')
        ╵                      ~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "pg-native" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove
  this error. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this   
  failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.

Environment: win32, node 16.14.0, framework 3.14.0 (local) 3.14.0v (global), plugin 6.2.1, SDK 4.3.2
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
Error: Build failed with 3 errors:
node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/s3_setup.js:43:28: ERROR: Could not resolve "mock-aws-s3"   
node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/s3_setup.js:112:23: ERROR: Could not resolve "nock"
node_modules/pg/lib/native/client.js:4:21: ERROR: Could not resolve "pg-native"
    at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Users\joaov\Desktop\lambda-ts\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1603:15) 
    at C:\Users\joaov\Desktop\lambda-ts\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1249:28
    at runOnEndCallbacks (C:\Users\joaov\Desktop\lambda-ts\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1162:65)   
    at buildResponseToResult (C:\Users\joaov\Desktop\lambda-ts\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1247:7)
    at C:\Users\joaov\Desktop\lambda-ts\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1356:14
    at C:\Users\joaov\Desktop\lambda-ts\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:666:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Users\joaov\Desktop\lambda-ts\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:763:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Users\joaov\Desktop\lambda-ts\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:632:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
PS C:\Users\joaov\Desktop\lambda-ts>
```

This is the code:
`package.json` dependencies:

```json
"dependencies": {
        "aws-lambda": "^1.0.7",
        "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
        "pg": "^8.7.3",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
        "typeorm": "^0.3.6",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2",
        "yup": "^0.32.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@serverless/typescript": "^3.8.0",
        "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.93",
        "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/node": "^17.0.25",
        "@types/pg": "^8.6.5",
        "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
        "esbuild": "^0.14.36",
        "serverless": "^3.14.0",
        "serverless-esbuild": "^1.26.2",
        "serverless-offline": "^8.7.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
        "typescript": "^4.6.3"
    }
```

```
// src/configs/consts.ts

import {
    AWS_RDS_POSTGRES,
    AWS_RDS_POSTGRES_DB,
    AWS_RDS_POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    AWS_RDS_POSTGRES_PORT,
    AWS_RDS_POSTGRES_USER
} from '@configs/env_vars';

export const HOST = AWS_RDS_POSTGRES;
export const PORT = AWS_RDS_POSTGRES_PORT;
export const DATABASE = AWS_RDS_POSTGRES_DB;
export const USER = AWS_RDS_POSTGRES_USER;
export const PASSWORD = AWS_RDS_POSTGRES_PASSWORD;
```

```
// src/database/config.ts

import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '@entities/User';
import { HOST, PORT, DATABASE, USER, PASSWORD } from '@configs/consts';

export const connConfig = new DataSource({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: HOST,
    port: Number(PORT),
    database: DATABASE,
    username: USER,
    password: PASSWORD,
    synchronize: false,
    entities: [User],
    migrations: []
});
```

```
// src/entities/User.ts

import { BaseEntity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

export class User extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    age: number;

    @Column()
    password: string;
}
```

```
// src/lambdas/CreateUser

import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda';
import { handle } from '@services/CreateUser';
import { connConfig } from '@database/config';
import { userSchema } from '@validations/UserSchema';

export const handler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    try {
        const { body } = event;
        const parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
        userSchema.isValid(parsedBody).catch(() => {
            throw Error('Invalid user data.');
        });

        const user = await handle(connConfig, parsedBody);

        if (!user) {
            return {
                statusCode: 400,
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    message: "Couldn't create user."
                })
            };
        }

        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'User created successfully.',
                user
            })
        };
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                error: (error as Error).message
            })
        };
    }
};
```

```
// src/services/CreateUser

import 'reflect-metadata';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { hash } from 'bcrypt';
import { User } from '@entities/User';

export const handle = async (dataSource: DataSource, userData: User): Promise<User | undefined> => {
    try {
        await dataSource.initialize();
        const user = new User();
        const { name, password, age } = userData;
        user.name = name;
        user.age = age;

        const hashedPassword = await hash(password, 10);
        user.password = hashedPassword;

        const savedUser = await dataSource.manager.save(user);

        return savedUser;
    } catch (error) {
        throw Error("Couldn't connect to database.");
    }
};
```

```
// src/validations/UserSchema

import * as yup from 'yup';

export const userSchema = yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().required(),
    age: yup.number().required(),
    password: yup.string().required()
});
```

What should I do in order to fix that and get a working aws-lambda + typeorm?

Comment: Anyone please help here, I have no idea of what's happening and need to use typeorm with serverless...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're using esbuild to bundle your lambdas? Some node modules don't like being bundled with esbuild and you have to add them as externals. Try adding to esbuild config:

```yaml
external:
 - pg-native
 - mock-aws-s3
 - nock
```

Comment: Hi...Do you know if it's possible avoid bundle some folders?...I need some "static" folders in my project but everything is bundled

Answer (score 1):

In case it might help anyone else -

I'm using AWS SAM, and I had to add the configuration suggested by Misha to `template.yaml`.

I added it to the `Metadata` section (under `Resources`), like this:

```
Metadata: # Manage esbuild properties
  BuildMethod: esbuild
  BuildProperties:
    Minify: true
    Target: "es2020"
    Sourcemap: true # Enabling source maps will create the required NODE_OPTIONS environment variables on your lambda function during sam build
    EntryPoints:
    - app.ts
    External: # <<------------------- I added this
     - pg-native
     - mock-aws-s3
     - nock
```

Comment: I am also using aws sam , could you please let me know how to solve this for aws rds mysql. I tried finding right libs But could not succeedd.

Comment: @Charlie IIRC that's all I did, and I was able to use RDS MySQL. But eventually I was disappointed with TypeORM... I kept running into annoying issues, and also felt it underdelivered in its core offering (e.g. it didn't handle automatic loading of cascading entities as well as I would have liked). Eventually I threw it out and just implemented a simple DB layer myself (I had pretty basic requirements and just a handful of entities in that project).

Comment: thank you..  I could resolve it now, without adding any additional stuff. But you are right, I am also running annoying issues, specially dealing with dates. unfortunately I cannot replace typeORM due to some constraints now.

Answer (score 0):

This error is particulary from bcrypt library. Replace your bcrypt to bcyptjs.
"bcrypt" to "bcryptjs".